# How to make a VB script count how many times it mas launched?

Tags: vbscript

I want to make my VB script count how many times I launched it and write the number into a file on the hard drive - something similiar to that batch file.

```
@echo off
if not exist "C:\Users\User\Desktop\run.log" goto end
if exist "C:\Users\User\Desktop\run.log" goto 123
:123
for /f "delims=" %%x in (C:\Users\User\Desktop\run.log) do set var=%%x
Set /A result = %var% + 1
echo %result% > "C:\Users\User\Desktop\run.log"
exit
:end
echo 1 > "C:\Users\User\Desktop\run.log"
exit
```

I tried this code below. At the first run, it works just fine, but after that [it doesn't](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvSQB.png):

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    If objFSO.FileExists("C:\Users\User\Desktop\run.log") Then
        Dim InputFile
        Dim oFile
        Dim ReadAll
        Dim data
        InputFile = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\run.log"
        Set oFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(InputFile)
        data = oFile.ReadAll
        Set sum = "data + 1"
        oFile.Close
        objFSO.DeleteFile("C:\Users\User\Desktop\run.log")
        outFile="C:\Users\User\Desktop\run.log"
        Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(outFile,True)
        objFile.Write "sum"
        objFile.Close
    Else
        outFile="C:\Users\User\Desktop\run.log"
        Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(outFile,True)
        objFile.Write "1"
        objFile.Close
    End If
```

Comment: `Set sum = "data + 1"` doesn't do what you think it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made multiple mistakes. I have updated the code with comments to make you understand the flow. Of course you can improve the code once you understand the flow.

Try below

```
Dim InputFile
Dim countText
Dim objFSO, oFile

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
InputFile = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\run.log"
If objFSO.FileExists(InputFile) Then
    'Read the file
    Set oFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(InputFile, 1, True)
    countText = oFile.ReadLine
    If IsNumeric(countText) Then
        MsgBox "Numeric"
        Count = CInt(countText) + 1
    Else
        Count = 1
    End If
    oFile.Close
    Set oFile = Nothing

    'Overwrite the file
    Set oFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(InputFile, 2, True)
    oFile.Write (CStr(Count))
Else
    Set oFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(InputFile, True)
    oFile.Write "1"
End If

'Close and Remove from memory 
oFile.Close
Set oFile = Nothing
Set objFSO = Nothing
```

Comment: Yes, that worked. I'm new to VBS, so sorry for being a noob!